# Access value of a dropdown selected item without posting the data

Tags: php, html

I am new to php. Is there any way to access the value of selected item in a drop down menu without posting the data on the same form?

Comment: Not in PHP, as PHP runs on server side and needs the browser posting the data.

Comment: @Pekka웃: But if I submit the form, is there anyway to keep the selected item as it is? Because I think it will reload the form and set the selected value to default one.

Comment: What one usually does in that case is to check using PHP what the selected value was (eg. `$_POST["elementname"]` and then set the `selected` property (using PHP) to the right value.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is the answer:

```
<script>
    function getDropDownInfo() {
        var objDropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
        alert(objDropdown.value);
    }
</script>

<form>
    <select name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
        <option value="one">one</option>
        <option value="two">two</option>
    </select>
</form>

<button onClick="getDropDownInfo();">get the data</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a php guy, but generally you would do this sort of thing with Javascript. In JQuery you'd use something like

```
$('#elementid option:selected').text();
```

Hope that's what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saying you need to access the value without posting it (means without communicating server), the task can be handled by client side scripting. You can use javascript for the instance.

Javascript:

```
<script lang='javascript'>
    var e = document.getElementById("test_id");
    var selectedValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(selectedValue);
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<select id="test_id">
    <option value="1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">Item 3</option>
</select>
```

[Check out in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TNANW/)